# umbraco 7 - users added via back end can't login

Tags: umbraco7

I'm working on a reasonably fresh install of umbraco (7.1.8).  I've only installed three plugins at the moment, so I don't believe they are the issue.

If I login using the id created during the install process, I can login fine.  But now I want to start adding other users to allow them to add content, and I can't seem to get the users created so they can get access to the back end.

I've double and triple checked the passwords (even using the reset password and copy/pasting from one browser to the next).  I've tried using both the email address and the login, but no joy in either scenario.  I've tried to just make this first account an admin - no joy.

I opened the console and found this error on the console:

POST /umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoApi/Authentication/PostLogin 400 Bad Request 114ms

I'm hoping it's something glaringly obvious, but I can't see it for the life of me.

Comment: Resolved.  Apparently, login and email address must match, or the account doesn't work.  Why there are two fields then, I don't know, but that's what fixed it for me....

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue a while back in version 6 where members created programmatically would not be able to login once they updated their email address. Had to ensure that the login was the same as the email address in order for them to login the next time. It is rather confusing I must admit.

Ensure login field value of user = email address field value of user

Comment: That is the answer